# Unable to push docker image to hub.docker.com

Tags: docker

I am building a Multiplatform image using `docker buildx`

After the image builds, I get errors of the form

```
 => ERROR exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            3976.3s
....
exporting to image:
498.0 error: failed to copy: failed to do request: Put "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/...
    write tcp 199.199.199.1:48296->3.216.34.172:443: write: connection reset by peer
```

and I am unable to push my image. This is is not something that happens randomly but every time I try the build.

Do you have any ideas of what the problem may be or how I can track it down?

This is an example of the command I run:

```
% docker login
% docker buildx build --push -t myusername/timescale-ha-db --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t some-db -f Dockerfile-postgres .
```

and I was expecting the image to be pushed to my docker hub repository. Notice that I have logged in successfully before running the build and I can usually push single platform images easily.

Comment: Network connections sometimes fail.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes not all times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your command, you provide two tags
`-t myusername/timescale-ha-db` and later on
`-t some-db`